# Css scrolling and sizing

Tags: html, css, scroll, zurb-foundation

I have a very simple problem

With the picture :

[image]

I would like the map to be totally static and take 100% of the height and the other part to be scrollable without the filter to be scrollable and take all the rest of the screen and to be responsive.

for the moment i have put manually

```
 .searchresults {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 600px;
}
```

and

```
.map{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

I just have a small css problem here.

If anyone can help me with that i'll be happy, thanks in advance !

EDIT : Maybe there is a problem with what i'm selecting in the html :

```
<div class="small-12 large-4  columns mapblock">
    <div class="responsive-embed map">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the map and result are in a div.

I'm using the framework foundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `css` will fix your map at `top-right` corner with `100%` height

You can go through this `css`

```
.map{
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this CSS for the div in which the map code.

overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;

Comment: Why the overflow attribute? I don't think this will solve the problem

Comment: Yes me too i don't see how overflow scroll can help me on that. Unfortunately 100% is not working it's not taking the full height of the screen :/

Answer (score 0):

You can start to this with `height:100vh`and `position:fixed` to the map wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the map

```
position:fixed;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
```

Same with the filter. height:1000 will just leave a blank space at the top

(sorry can't comment)

Comment: Have you given it a z-index? If you want it to stick on top of the screen you need to give it a high z-index, any value, as long as it is the highest value you give.
Alternatively try giving the map

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

Example:
    .map {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1030;}


If your map is not taking up the full height you might need to resize it.

Comment: z-index does not solve the problem at all because it for the order of how componenent show and if they can be one in front of another

Comment: Yes and you want that element to always be on top of the others if you are making it fixed.